# Define custom function in Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am a chronic user of Firebug, and I frequently need to `log` various stuff so that I can see what I am doing. The `console.log` function is a lot to type. Even if I assign it to a single letter variable like `q = console.log`, I have to do it every time I fire up Firebug. Is there any way to do it such that `q` always refer to `console.log` (unless, of course, I override it in my session)?

Comment: what about `co<down><enter>.l<tab>`?

Comment: Well, where do I add that? And what does it do? And how does it do that?

Comment: In the console: type `co`, wait for the dropdown to appear, press down and enter to select `console`, type `.l`, wait for the `log` hint to appear, press tab to confirm.

Comment: The question itself is interesting (defining a function that's only visible from Firebug; of course then there are user scripts), but you'd need to show me a better motivation. `console.log` is way too easy to type, especially with autocomplete.

Comment: Well, being lazy is the quintessential motivation, ain't it? I mean, that alone prompted Larry Wall to come up with Perl. Here's the next Larry Wall in the making, won't you support him adequately? :P

Comment: By the way,I type `co`, pressed the `Run` button below, and got something like **ReferenceError: co is not defined** on the left..

Comment: Is writing a userscript an adequate solution for you, or do you mind that your alias will be visible for ordinary javascript?

Comment: Alternatively, write an (also trivial) autohotkey script

Comment: I don't know how to do either. I just want that whenever I start Firebug and type something like `q('some stuff')`, `q` will behave like `console.log`...I am fine with either userscript or autohotkey script (whatever they are!).

Comment: Autohotkey: `#ifWinActive firefox` `::q{Tab}::console.log(`

Comment: Where do I do this? I mean, where to type it and save it for future sessions?

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: For a userscript, look up some [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/cs/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) tutorials. Basically, you just write some javascript (`window.q=console.log.bind(console)`) that will execute on each page load, add some meta-data, feed to greasemonkey and voila - `q` is an alias for `console.log` everywhere you go.

Comment: How do I integrate AutoHotKey with Firebug? I mean they are completely disjoint. One is an app running within an another app (Firefox), while the other is a standalone dektop software...

Comment: AutoHotKey will come with you everywhere you go. If you want to restrict it to just some applications, use the `#ifWinActive` directive.

Comment: Okay, will try it and ask for help if needed...

Comment: Hmm haven't though about a greasemonkey script as a viable solution, but indeed, you have a rather limited subset of pages where you would want to run that script (localhost, *.yourCompanyLAN etc.). Anyway it's still some penalty **on each page load** even when Firebug is off.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the functionality doesn't currently exist, however I have found the firebug developers to be very responsive in the past.  Why don't you put in a feature request on their forum, or better yet, code it up yourself, and ask them to add it?

Comment: Yep, actually something like `.bash_profile` thing for Firebug could be useful. However I'm concerned about the performance, because each Firebug attached to each tab opened is a kind of separate "process" within Firefox (at least I see it works this way). But if this "profile script" was kept small, it should not be a severe penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IDE, simply setup a code snippet (I use Flash Develop, so Tools -> Code Snippets).

I believe this to be a better way than setting up redirect scripts and what not, because it stops the Firebug namespace from being polluted, and makes it easier/more consistent to debug if your debugging breaks down.

The screenshot shows me using Flash Develop, hitting `Ctrl+B`, then hit `enter`. The pipe (`|`) in the snippet indicates where the cursor will be placed to start typing after inserting the snippet.

[image]